# Air Native Extensions for OSX without flat_namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing Air Native Extensions for Adobe Air application for Mac.
Extension is a .framework with c++ code and ActionScript wrapper.
It uses custom sqlite (3.8) library as static library to handle some search issues.
But after air application start it automatically loads (from CFNetwork) system libsqlite.dylib (3.7) and all functions are called from this library.
Adobe recommends using -flat_namespace option for build framework. Without this option everything works fine but as Adobe says:
"Together, these option settings allow the application to load the correct copy of the AIR framework first, and then for the extension to rely on the already loaded copy." So I'm afraid to turn it off.
So what can be affected without this option?